# Why do we have this behavior in a Python dictionary generator?

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

Why in the first case the dictionary keys have been overwritten, but in the second case the values have been overwritten?

```
>>> a = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 3}}
>>> {None if v.__class__ == dict else k: v for k, v in a.items()}
{'a': 1, None: {'c': 3}}
>>> {k: v if v.__class__ != dict else None for k, v in a.items()}
{'a': 1, 'b': None}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's clearer with parentheses: `{(None if v.__class__ == dict else k): v for ...}` vs. `{k: (v if v.__class__ != dict else None) for ...}`. Why would you expect it **not** to be different?!

Comment: If you wanted to skip keys with dictionary values, it should be `{k: v for k, v in a.items()  if not isinstance(v, dict)}`, which both: puts the conditional in the correct place; and tests for dictionaries in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we rewrite as a standard loop, the situation may become clearer (note that I've used `isinstance` as a better class check):

**Option 1**:

```
d = {}
for k, v in a.items():
    d[None if isinstance(v, dict) else k] = v
```

**Option 2**:

```
d = {}
for k, v in a.items():
    d[k] = None if isinstance(v, dict) else v
```

Clearly the former is modifying the keys, the latter is modifying the values.

---

You don't say what you *actually* wanted to happen, but if you were trying to *skip over* `k: v` pairs where the value is a dictionary, i.e.:

```
d = {}
for k, v in a.items():
    if not isinstance(v, dict):
        d[k] = v
```

then the *"dictionary comprehension"* equivalent would look like:

```
{k: v for k, v in a.items() if not isinstance(v, dict)}
```

Note that the `if` condition appearing *after* the `for` acts as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You are only selecting key on basis of condition, the value remains same whether if is executed or else. Parenthesis would make it more readable.

```
{(None if v.__class__ == dict else k): v for k, v in a.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because if...else binds more tightly than :. And it's good it does, since otherwise you'd have {('a': 1), None}, and that's not a dict. :-)

You probably wanted

```
{k: v for k, v in a.items() if not isinstance(v, dict)}
```

But be careful: are you *really* singling out just dicts here? Or any mapping? Or anything that's not an int? Or...

Answer (score 0):

See the language spec on [dict comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-dict_comprehension):

If you analyze the dict-comprehension `None if v.__class__ == dict else k: v for k, v in a.items()` it will have to match the form `expression : expression comp_for`. So let's look at what `comp_for` could be. It states that `comp_for` would have to start with `for` and there's only one for in it so `for k, v in a.items()` is the `for_comp` and the rest would need to be on the form `expression : expression`, but there's only one colon so the first expression (ie the key) would be `None if v.__class__ == dict else k` and the second (ie the value) `v`. The `if` and `else` are part of a conditional expression.

The comprehension means that for each `k, v` in `a.items` form a key-value pair with the key `None` if `v.__class__` == dict and `k` otherwise and the value being `v`.